# The basis of special linear Lie algebras over finite fields

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-algebras, finite-fields, semisimple-lie-algebras

Let $n\geq 2$ be an integer and $p$ a prime with $ p>n $. Let $ \mathfrak{sl}_{n}(\mathbb{F}_{p})$ denote the special linear Lie algebra over a finite field $ \mathbb{F}_{p} $, i.e. the space of $ n\times n $ matrices with trace zero over $ \mathbb{F}_{p} $ with the Lie bracket $ [X,Y]=XY-YX $. Note that our assumption implies that $ \mathfrak{sl}_{n}(\mathbb{F}_{p}) $ is a simple Lie algebra over $\mathbb{F}_p$.

**Question:** Given a family $\{b_{ij}\}_{i,j\in I} $ of elements in $ \mathbb{F}_{p} $ where $ I=\{1,\cdots,n^{2}-1\} $ and $ b_{ij}=0 $ if $ i=j $. Suppose that at least one of $ b_{ij},b_{ji} $ is non-zero for all $ i\neq j $. Is it true that there is no basis $ \{A_{i}\}_{i\in I} $ of $ \mathfrak{sl}_{n}(\mathbb{F}_{p}) $ such that
$$ \sum_{j\neq i}b_{ij}[A_{i},A_{j}]=0 ?$$
When $n=2$, we find that $ [A_{1},A_{2}],[A_{1},A_{3}],[A_{2},A_{3}] $ must be linearly independent since $ \mathfrak{sl}_{2}(\mathbb{F}_{p}) $ is a simple Lie algebra. From this, it's easy to see that the answer to the question is Yes. But I have no idea for $n\geq 3$. Any comments and reference would be highly appreciated.

Comment: "Suppose that at least one of $b_{ij},b_{ji}$ is non-zero for all $i \neq j$": I'm a bit unsure of the order of quantifiers when formalizing this. I assume you mean that for each pair $(i,j)$ with $i \neq j$, $b_{ij} \neq 0$ or $b_{ji} \neq 0$ (or both). Correct?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Yes.

Comment: Isn't the sum trivially $0$, for any $A_i$ (in particular all possible bases) if I set $b_{ji}:=b_{ij} \neq 0$ randomly for all $i < j$? Just because $[A_i, A_j] = - [A_j, A_i]$ I mean. You might need to be more restrictive about those $b_{ij}$.

Comment: ? My argument shows that for many families of $b_{ij}'s$, any basis $A_i$ will satisfy this equation, so the answer to the question "Is it true there is no basis [...]" is "no".

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Yes, you're right. (The previous comment has been deleted.)

Comment: In fact, one should maybe ask about $\sum_{i<j} c_{ij}[A_i, A_j]$ instead, which we get from your question via $c_{ij} := b_{ij}-b_{ji}$. There are $\frac{(n^2-1)(n^2-2)}{2}$ such summands though, and via simplicity the $[A_i, A_j]$ generate the full space, whose dimension $n^2-1$ is less than that number of summands for all $n \ge 3$. So I can say that for any basis $A_i$, I will find certain $c_{ij}$, not all $0$, which make the equation true. If one can always find $A_i$ for a given tuple of $c_ij$, *all* $\neq 0$, I have no clue.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Thank you very much for your detailed explanation, and it's helpful for me.